# Find raspberry pi from android

Tags: android, node.js

I made a nodejs service for my raspberry and i am working on an application to communicate with the service. Is it possible that the application find the raspberry IP on a Local Network automatically? What is the better way?

I wan't my app find automatically the ip of raspberry to communicate it.

Thank´s and sorry, I am learning english.

Comment: It sounds like you might want a scheme for service discovery.  One such scheme is [Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_(software)) which is available on NPM in pure Javascript form (so it should work on the raspberry Pi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have a fixed local IP address you can keep them in touch through a broadcast receiver which listens in background for a specific event. In this case it could be a message of the Pi

Comment: Thanks for help me, but that is the problem, i wan´t that it works with dinamically ip, because I have to show a prototype and I will move the raspberry pi to diferent places, and can have different ip´s on any network.

Comment: Try to use a mnemonic address linked to your variable Ip.. There are a lot of services which implement this service. Try for example to this link: http://freedns.afraid.org/